# Excepcion en el main al entrar en case 2

Tags: java

Me da fallo de excepcion, eclipse me dice que es la linea que esta marcada(**) llevo dias intentandolo y no consigo nada.Gracias

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean menu = true;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos alumnos quiere?");
        int numAlumnos = Leer.entero();
        String alumnos [] = new String [numAlumnos];
        while(menu) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca una opción:");
        System.out.println("\t1. Introducir nombres");
        System.out.println("\t2. Notas del alumno");
        System.out.println("\t8. Exit");
        int opcion = Leer.entero();
        String[][] notas = new String[4][alumnos.length];
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("******INTRODUZCA LOS NOMBRES*******");
                for(int i = 0;i<alumnos.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println("Indique el nombre del "+(i+1)+"º alumno");
                    alumnos[i] = Leer.texto();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("******INTRODUZCA LAS NOTAS*******");
                for(int i = 0;i<alumnos.length;i++) {
                    for(int j = 1; j<4;j++) {
                        System.out.println("La nota de "+alumnos[i]+" del "
                                + (j)+"º Trimestre es: ");
                    **  notas[i][j] = Leer.texto();
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Comment: Bienvenido edita tu pregunta y pon el fallo que te da el log

Comment: tómate el tiempo de leer [ask] tu título de pregunta no es nada descriptivo, no necesitas poner `principiante` sino pones a detalle que error da y cual es el resultado esperado probablemente no recibas ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercambia los índices: usa `notas[j][i] = ...`, porque según la declaración

```
String[][] notas = new String[4][alumnos.length];
```

tienes un array de 4 elementos, donde cada uno tiene N alumnos.

Y es `j` el que está limitado a ser menor que 4 e `i` el que está limitado a ser menor que N:

```
for(int i = 0;i<alumnos.length;i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j<4;j++) {
        ...
        notas[i][j] = Leer.texto(); // i sobrepasa 4 y te da un ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha servido para solucionarlo y entenderlo